# how to use d3.js in sonarqube widgets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, d3.js, widget, sonarqube

I want to show a d3 chart on my sonarqube widget. in my plugin I execute my tool Exe file and generate a json file. I want to know that

- where I put my json file so it acceptable  to localhost so I can read
  from erb file.
- when I put my json file in web folder of sonarqube it acceptable to localhost but when I run sonarqube I only get two radio button nothing else so whats the problem.
  I use this code:http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063423
- if there is other method to do this job please tell me
  thank you

Edit:
Now I'm able to show the chart on sonarqube dashboard but the chart and widget are not showing properly as you see in the blow picture. I just want to show chart within my widget. as I mention earlier i use the same code as given here:  http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063423.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be declaring new Metrics & saving your data into them during analysis rather than out to json file. Then your widgets will be able to read your data using standard means & you can peek at any of the open source plugins to see how.

Comment: you mean to say it's no way we can do this with json file.

Comment: I won't say it's impossible @Rohit. With enough time and determination most things are. But it's just not the way the platform is designed to work.

Comment: thank you @G. Ann  for your valuable time but I want to do with my way.

Comment: please answer my edited question or give me some idea thank you

Comment: You're down to a rendering error at this point. Assuming you have no errors in your JavaScript console, you should post your widget code.

Comment: thank you now it's done firstly i try to extend the body which is default code of the link I post in my question my silly mistake.